# Matrix power series has linearly dependent terms

Tags: linear-algebra, alternative-proof

Prove that for any $(n\times n)$ real matrix, the set of matrices $\{I,M,M^2,...,M^n\}$ are linearly dependent.

More formally, we have to prove that
$$\forall M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n},\\ 
\exists (a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n)\neq (0,0,\ldots,0) \\
\text{such that}\;\; \sum_{i=0}^n a_i M^i =0\,\,.   $$

I have a solution which I will post below, but I would like to see if anyone has a more intuitive or elegant proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [characteristic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_equation), 
$$\det(M-\lambda I)=0 $$ 
is an order $n$ polynomial in $\lambda$, ie
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \lambda^i=0\,\,.$$

The [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) states that $M$ solves this equation which proves our theorem.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: @Traklon has pointed out that this does not prove the above theorem.  It only proves the special case for which $M$ is [diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Diagonalizable_matrices). My bad!

We start with the expression
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i M^i$$
and attempt to prove that there is some choice for the $\{a_i\}$ that makes this become zero.

We then diagonalize $M$, giving $M=C^{-1}DC$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with complex elements.  Substituting this into the expression above and using the relation $M^p=C^{-1}D^pC$ for an integer $p$, we get
\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^n a_i M^i &=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i C^{-1}D^iC \\ &= C^{-1}\left\{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i D^i\right\}C\tag 2\end{align}

Since the set of matrices $\{D^0,D^1,D^2,\dots,D^n\}$ has $n+1$ elements, but only $n$ degrees of freedom (corresponding to its $n$ non-zero elements), it must be a linearly dependent set.  That is to say that for some choice of the $\{a_i\}$,
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i D^i = 0\,.$$

Plugging this into Eq (2) shows that for some choice of $\{a_i\}$, 
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i M^i=0$$
QED.

Comment: My linear algebra courses are a little bit far, but you said "Since $M$ is a square matrix, it can be diagonalized, $M=C^{-1}DC$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with complex elements.". I think it can only be triangularized, am I wrong ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that any real (or complex) square matrix can be diagonalized.  I think this is proven by looking at the [characteristic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_equation) of the matrix.  This will be a polynomial of order $n$ and by the [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), $\lambda$ will have $n$ complex values (counted with multiplicity), corresponding to $n$ eigenvectors.

Comment: This is not true. For real matrices because not every polynomial has roots, and for complex matrices because the roots may have multiplicities > 1. A block like $(\lambda{}-1)^3$ in the characteristic polynomial doesn't imply that there are 3 lineary independant eigenvectors of eigenvalues 1, which is required to diagonalise the matrix. It only tells you that 1 is an eigenvalue.

Comment: I insist because it is very important. Not every matrix can be diagonalised. For example, consider $\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$. The characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda{}-1)^2$, but you won't be able to find a basis formed of two linearily independant eigenvectors. This only tells you that 1 is an eigenvalue so it has at least 1 eigenvector. One consequence of this is that if all the roots of the characteristic polynomial have multiplicity 1, then the matrix is diagonalisable (it is not an equivalence, just an implication).

Comment: You're right. Thanks!